# What blocks can you use to put under a beacon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a survival world and I don't know which blocks can go under a beacon?

Answer (score 4):

From the [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon), emphasis mine:

> #### Activation
>
> In order to activate a beacon, the beacon must adhere to the following requirements
>
> - Beacons require an unobstructed view of the sky, though bedrock and transparent blocks (including water, lava, slime, and other beacon blocks) will not count as obstruction.
> - The beacon is on top of **a pyramid constructed from iron blocks, gold blocks, emerald blocks, and/or diamond blocks**.

Answer (score 1):

To activate a beacon, you need to make a pyramid of iron blocks, Diamond blocks, Gold blocks, or Emerald blocks [You can use all of them]. At the top in the middle of a 3 by 3 square put the beacon and then later it should glow.

This is what it should look like at any size:
[image: Beacon]

But hey don't go away! [SPOILER!]:

> If you put a stained glass block on the beacon block, the glow will change color depending what color the stained glass block is. You can blend the colors too!

Answer (score 1):

With the new update you can also use Netherite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would use any pyramid material other than Iron. The effect depends on the amount of layers, not on the value of the material, so if Iron is the cheapest option, there's no reason to use anything else. Gold, Diamond, Emerald (since 1.14), and especially the new Netherite are very valuable and shouldn't be wasted on a beacon.

Gold can be used for:

1. Golden Carrots (best food in the game)
2. Golden Apples (amazing regeneration effect)
3. Crafting Netherite Ingots (best material in the game)

Diamond can be used for:

1. Diamond Tools and Weapons (2nd best material, can be turned into the best material)
2. Jukebox (useless but fun)

Emerald can be used for trading with Vilagers, their trades can actually be useful since 1.14

And Netherite is just straight up OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iron, Gold(I think), Diamond, and Emerald blocks.

Comment: Try expanding on your answer. Also, a Gold Block is a valid ore block that can be used.

Answer (score -2):

iron blocks, gold blocks, emerald blocks, and diamond blocks.

Comment: I guess answering the question is a bad thing because I keep getting downvotes on most of my questions. Okay then.

Comment: You are free to answer the question, but everything after what actually answers the question here is not useful and detracts from what would otherwise be a good answer. A great many questions on Arqade could be answered elsewhere by google. That does *not* mean the questions should not be asked.